# Understanding Docker and micro-services

Tags: asp.net, docker, microservices

All, Forgive me I just an newbie for `Docker` and `Micro-services`. I am going to to get into the world of `Micro-services` and `Docker`. But currently I have no idea of how to get started with them. I have the experience of `Asp.net`. I heard of `Asp.net core`can work in the `Linux`.
I want to know what is the `Docker`. how does it work. how `Docker` help to build `Micro-services`. Is it `Docker` is the only way to host `Micro-services`? Thanks.

Comment: Please recommend which website should I post this question. Thanks.

Comment: :( I just didn't know which site of SO should I post ?

Answer (score 2):

> what is the Docker

The [Docker docs](https://www.docker.com/what-docker) are the best place to learn about Docker.

> how Docker help to build Micro-services?

Docker doesn't help in building microservices, it helps in packaging, deploying, and shipping microservices. However, Docker is a great tool to grab all the dependencies needed to develop services in general, from database to cloud components ...

> Is it Docker is the only way to host Micro-services

No Docker is not the only way to deploy microservices, however it is probably the most popular way nowadays to package and deploy services.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply. I was reading the docs. In my understanding .the docker client is just a CLI. Is it right ? thanks

Comment: @joe.wang Yes. Though there are some gui wrappers for the client cli.